# How to combine a pattern analyzer and char_filter in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a keyword field that I would like to tokenize (split on commas), but it may also contain values with "+" characters. For example:

```
query_string.keywords = Living,Music,+concerts+and+live+bands,News,Portland
```

When creating the index the following does a nice job of splitting the keywords on commas:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 5,
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "happy_tokens": {
                    "type":      "pattern",
                    "pattern":   "([,]+)"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "post" : {
            "properties" : {
                "query_string.keywords" : {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer" : "happy_tokens"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I add a char_filter (see below) to this to change the +'s to spaces or empty strings?

```
        "char_filter": {
            "kill_pluses": {
                "type": "pattern_replace",
                "pattern": "+",
                "replace": ""
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered the "mapping" `char_filter` that can take my plus characters to spaces. After tokenizing I was able to `trim` the tokens to remove white space.

The [custom analyzers page in the elasticsearch guide](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/custom-analyzers.html) was a big help.

My working example is below:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 5,
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "char_filter": {
                    "plus_to_space": {
                        "type": "mapping",
                        "mappings": ["+=>\\u0020"]
                    }
                },
                "tokenizer": {
                    "split_on_comma": {
                        "type": "pattern",
                        "pattern": "([,]+)"
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "happy_tokens": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "char_filter": ["plus_to_space"],
                        "tokenizer": "split_on_comma",
                        "filter": ["trim"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "post" : {
            "properties" : {
                "query_string.keywords" : {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer" : "happy_tokens"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So that was way more involved than anything I had expected. Kudos for a job well done!

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your "+", as "+" has a [special meaning](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#regexp-syntax) in regular expressions.

```
    "char_filter": {
        "kill_pluses": {
            "type": "pattern_replace",
            "pattern": "\+",
            "replace": ""
        }
    }
```

Comment: The docs say "Additionally, any characters (except double quotes) are interpreted literally when surrounded by double quotes", so I'm not sure if that's an issue, but I will check. Any ideas on how to add the character filter prior to the tokenizer?